# Nativescript nfc plugin seems not working

Tags: angular, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I'm trying to read from nfc and only find one plugin in natviescript marketplace.

https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-nfc

It can detect and enable the nfc (log on console). but it's callback function are not getting called when nfc is readed, just play a sound. nothing else.

Here is the code for my demo.

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Nfc, NfcNdefData, NfcTagData } from "nativescript-nfc";
import { Subject } from "rxjs";

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class NfcReaderService {
    nfcData = new Subject();


    private nfc: Nfc = new Nfc();

    constructor() {
        this.nfc.available().then((avail) => {
            this.nfc.enabled().then((on) => {
                if (on) {
                    console.log("NFC Enabled!!!");
                    this.readNFC();
                    this.onTagDiscoverd();
                } else {
                    console.log("NFC Not Enabled");
                }
            });
        });
    }

    public readNFC() {
        this.nfc.setOnNdefDiscoveredListener((data: NfcNdefData) => {
            console.log("Nfc Data: ", data);
            this.nfcData.next(data);
            if (data.message) {
                for (let m in data.message) {
                    let record = data.message[m];
                    console.log("Ndef discovered! Message record: " + record.payloadAsString);
                }
            }
        });
    }


    public onTagDiscoverd() {
        this.nfc.setOnTagDiscoveredListener((data: NfcTagData) => {
            console.log("Discovered a tag with ID " + data.id);
        }).then(() => {
            console.log("OnTagDiscovered listener added");
        });
    }

}
```

Here is the log output

```
NFC Enabled!!!
JS: OnTagDiscovered listener added
```

What can be quickest and effective way to read from nfc chip ?

Comment: Are you sure the NFC tag has data and readable? Did you cross verify it with the other NFC application or the default one (if any) on your device?

Comment: yes, i checked by another nfc-reader application.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? Looks like I am stuck on the same issue :(

Comment: @CodeMonkey No bro, I build my app using __flutter__. Flutter is more productive and developer friendly.